# Зачем нам нужны middleware redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, асинхронность, redux-thunk

У меня в приложении есть логика регистрации и авторизации

Есть такой код:

Это функция которую я вызываю на кнопке onSubmit при логине

```
import store from "redux/store";

export const login = async (data) => {
 try {

    const res = await api.login(data);

    if(res.status < 300) {
        store.dispatch(setUserData(res.data))
    }

 } catch(err) {
    alert(err)
 }

}
```

Чем такой способ dispatch'а отличается от подобного, с использованием redux-thunk?

```
export const loginAction = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {

    const res = await api.login(data);

    if(res.status < 300) {
        dispatch(setUserData(res.data))
    }

 } catch(err) {
    alert(err)
 }
}
```

Есть ли какая-нибудь разница вообще? И если есть, то какой способ лучше использовать и почему? Почему redux настоятельно рекомендует использовать инструменты по типу middleware redux-thunk, ведь мои действия и так асинхронны, я делаю dispatch только тогда, когда мне пришел ответ от сервера?

Comment: [Вот тут объясняют](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWdnjfRu9Io&t=390s), зачем это надо(14:30, примерно). А еще у вас есть проверка статус кода ответа, но, в этом нет смысла, т.к. если будет ошибка, то просто отработает блок `catch` + 400, 500 коды тоже больше 200)

Comment: @ДимаЭф, со статус кодом опечатка, там должно быть res.status < 300, а в видео не говориться о том почему мы должны передавать функцию в dispatch чтобы из action можно было использовать dispatch если это можно сделать без middleware.

Comment: Тогда [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570758/why-do-we-need-middleware-for-async-flow-in-redux) посмотрите. А проверка статус кода вам, по идее, не нужна.